# Mongo Query Filter $lookup not filtering correctly

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 3 query's that as far as my knowledge goes should be synonymous, But they give very different results, And I am wondering if someone could help fill in my knowledge gap on this.

This one works perfect, and gives the exact result I am looking for, The user who created it

```
db.getCollection("core-navlink").aggregate([
    { $match : { id : "c1a13efc-1203-436b-a32c-e59a889c08a3" } },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from : "core-user",
            as : "created_by_user",
            let : { module_id : "$created_by.module_id" },
            pipeline : [
                { $match : {  $expr : { $and : [ {  $eq : [ "$id" ,  "$$module_id"] }  ] } } } 
            ]
        } 
    } 
]).projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

This one, "created_by_user" gives all user's not just the one I am looking for

```
db.getCollection("core-navlink").aggregate([
    { $match : { id : "c1a13efc-1203-436b-a32c-e59a889c08a3" } },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from : "core-user",
            as : "created_by_user",
            let : { module_id : "$created_by.module_id" },
            pipeline : [
                { $match : {  $expr : { $and : [ {  id :  "$$module_id"  } ] } } } 
            ]
        } 
    } 
]).projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

And this one gives no results back in the created_by_user array

```
db.getCollection("core-navlink").aggregate([
    { $match : { id : "c1a13efc-1203-436b-a32c-e59a889c08a3" } },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from : "core-user",
            as : "created_by_user",
            let : { module_id : "$created_by.module_id" },
            pipeline : [
                { $match : {     id :  "$$module_id"  }  } 
            ]
        } 
    } 
]).projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   .limit(100)
```

UPDATE : Example Documents
core-navlink: ( Minimized to only relevent fields )

```
{
  "_id": "c1a13efc-1203-436b-a32c-e59a889c08a3",
  "id": "c1a13efc-1203-436b-a32c-e59a889c08a3",
  "created_by": {
    "module_name": "USER",
    "module_id": "f0ae108f-7dca-4bd1-ba7a-bcf50d9f7814"
  }
}
```

core-user

```
{
  "_id": "f0ae108f-7dca-4bd1-ba7a-bcf50d9f7814",
  "id": "f0ae108f-7dca-4bd1-ba7a-bcf50d9f7814",
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "User",
}
```

Comment: If you can provide sample data from two collections, then it would be easy to say why, but as far as I can say : Maybe an issue because $and needs an operator $eq & also can you try using $id to say it's a field of 'core-navlink'

Comment: Hmmm!    Shouldn't need to use `$expr` in the agg framework; it's a retrofit for enhanced `find`.   Your last example "should" be the one that works.   Care to share a doc or two from `core-navlink` and `core-user`?

Comment: I updated it with an example of each data type

Answer (score 0):

Lookup doesn't work with pipeline attribute.
Please Correct me if assumes field name wrong.
Try as below:

```
db.getCollection("core-navlink").aggregate([
    { $match : { id : "c1a13efc-1203-436b-a32c-e59a889c08a3" } },
    {
        $lookup : {
            from : "core-user",
            localField: "module_id", // assumes this field on core-navlink
            foreignField: "_id", // assumes this field on "core-user"
            as : "created_by_user"

        } 
    } 
]);
```

Comment: As of version 3.6 pipeline's are supported https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#uncorrelated-subquery  , and my usecase does not allow a single field lookup

The first query in my example works perfectly, I am just trying to figure out why the other 2, which I though should be synonymous are not working